# Transpiling Bootstrap scss to css with modifications using Webpack?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, webpack, sass, frontend

In a .NET Core web app project, I've made a folder called 'client' to contain my custom scss files for the front end, overriding Bootstrap's scss. (The 'client' folder also contains js files but no need to override anything at the moment.) I've made a package.json like this, with the 'mytest' script meant to run Webpack and transpile the scss into css and put it into a file called wwwroot/mainly.css. In the _Layout.shtml I use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/mainly.css" /><script src="~/js/bundle.js"></script>`. How can I try out writing scss "on top" of the scss provided from Bootstrap? I assumed I could do it in my custom.scss below, but it doesn't seen to have any effect on the output. (Yes I run `npm run mytest` prior to building.)

custom.scss:

```
// Required
@import "/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";

// Optional
@import "/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/type";
@import "/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/images";
@import "/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/code";
@import "/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/grid";

$body-bg: #ffd800;
$body-color: #4cff00;
```

package.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^4.3.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.11.2",
    "postcss-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "sass": "^1.26.11",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "webpack": "^4.44.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.5.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "jquery-validation": "^1.19.2",
    "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "^3.2.11"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "bootstrap-js": "webpack --mode production --progress --profile --config webpack.bootstrap.js",
    "bootstrap-css": "node-sass --output-style compressed client/css/bootstrap.scss wwwroot/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "bundles": "npm run bootstrap-js && npm run bootstrap-css",
    "mytest": "webpack --mode development"
  }
}
```

My webpack.config.js:

```
  const webpack = require('webpack');
  const path = require('path');
  const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

const config = {
   entry: './client/js/index.js',
   output: {
       path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'wwwroot/js/'),
       filename: 'bundle.js'
   },
   plugins: [new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
           filename: '../css/mainly.css'
   })
   ],
   module: {
       rules: [
           {
               test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
               use: [
                   {
                       loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
                   },
                   'css-loader',
                   'sass-loader'
               ]
           }
       ]
   }
};

module.exports = config;
```

client/js/index.js:

```
import "../css/custom.scss";



console.log("Hello, you cruel front-end world.");
```

When I run `npm run mytest` this happens:
[image]

The output which doesn't seem to contain changes from custom.scss:

[image: output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `/\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/` instead of `/\.s[ac]ss$/` to catch the .sass, .scss and .css files.

The overrides should come before the bootstrap imports.

```
$body-bg: #ffd800;
$body-color: #4cff00;

// Required
@import "/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";

// Optional
@import "/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/type";
@import "/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/images";
@import "/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/code";
@import "/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/grid";
```

Comment: Placing the overrides before the imports fixed it! It wasn't necessary to modify regex as I was importing precompiled sass rather than compiled css.